# Close and open app and keep the last url visited in iOS webview

Tags: ios, wkwebview

I wish to open app with the latest url viewd on a webview ios app.
Tryied this inside viewdidload()

```
    var hasHistoryUrl = false
    WebView.evaluateJavaScript("window.location.href") {
        (result,error)->Void in if (result != nil){
            hasHistoryUrl=true
        }
    }
    
    if (hasHistoryUrl){
       // let url = URL(string: historyUrl)
    } else {
        let url = URL(string: "https://www.url.com/")
        let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        loadReq(request: request);
    }
```

Not working on true device, on emulators allways opens with a clear cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open your app, all variable initialise and your previous data will be gone. So you need to save latest visited url in userdefaults as string like-

```
let url: String = "abcd.com"
UserDefaults.standard.set(url, forKey: "MyUrl")
```

And fetch url from userdefaults when you open the app as -

```
if let urlString = UserDefaults.string(forKey: ""MyUrl"") {
    // Do stuff
}
```

**In your code, insert it as-**

```
    WebView.evaluateJavaScript("window.location.href") {
        (result,error)->Void in if (result != nil){
            UserDefaults.standard.set(yourURL, forKey: "MyUrl")
        }
    }
    
    if let urlString = UserDefaults.string(forKey: ""MyUrl"") {
        // Do stuff
    } else {
        let url = URL(string: "https://www.url.com/")
        let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        loadReq(request: request);
    }
```